# Transfinite induction on class of ordinals.

Tags: logic, proof-verification, set-theory, transfinite-induction

This was an exercise from Enderton's Text, Elements of Set Theory. I am unsure of my proof - and I wonder what other possible solutions there are.

> [7,25] (Transfinite induction schema) Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula and
>   show that the following holds:  $$ \text{ If $\forall \alpha, \, (
>  \forall  x \in \alpha) \phi(x) \Rightarrow \phi(\alpha) $. Then
> $\phi(\alpha)$ for any ordinal $\alpha$.}$$

**My thoughts (proof):** For ordinal $\alpha$, define set 
$$ B:= \{ x \in \alpha \, | \, \phi(x) \} $$
We apply transfinite induction principle (below) on the set $B \subseteq \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is well ordered by epsilon (by membership). If $\text{seg }x \subseteq B$, then $(\forall y \in x)\phi(y)$, hence, $\phi(x)$ by hypothesis of problem. So $x \in B$, and $B = \alpha$.

Consequently for any ordinal $\alpha$, $(\forall x \in \alpha)\phi(x)$ holds, and by hypothesis,  $\phi(\alpha)$.

> **Transfinite induction princple:** Transfinite Induction Principle: Assume that $<$ is a well ordering on $A$. Assume that $B$ is a subset
>   of $A$ with the special property that for every $t \in A$,  $$
> \text{seg } t \subseteq B \Rightarrow t \in B$$  Then $B$ conincides
>   with $A$.

Is this proof correct? Thank you so much!

---

> **Proof 2:** (hinted by Clive Newstand)
>
> Consider the class  $$B := \{ \alpha \, | \, \alpha \text{ is an
> ordinal } \, \& \,  \phi(\alpha) \text{ does not hold } \} $$ If $B$
>   is empty then we are done. Suppose $B$ is nonempty, there exist $\beta
> \in B$. Define the *set*,  $$B' = \{ x \in \beta \, | \, \phi(x) \text{ does not hold } \} $$ since any set of
>   ordinals is well ordered by epsilon, let $\alpha'$ be the least
>   element of $B'$. So for all $x \in \alpha'$, $\phi(x)$ holds, meaning
>    $\phi(\alpha')$ by hypothesis, contradiction.

@Clive Newstead, I wonder if the above proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you mention 'transfinite induction' in your proof of the principle of transfinite induction; in fact, you seem to be assuming the result to prove the result.

A clearer approach might be to suppose that $\phi(\alpha)$ is false for some ordinal $\alpha$. Fix the least such $\alpha$, and derive a contradiction using the assumption that $\phi(\alpha)$ is false.

Comment: Sorry, the induction I used in my proof was the transfinite induction for non class case, I will edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem** (Transfinite Induction). For each formula $\phi(\alpha)$, if for each ordinal $\beta$, if for each $\gamma\in\beta$, $\phi(\gamma)$ holds, then $\phi(\beta)$ holds, then for each ordinal $\alpha$, $\phi(\alpha)$ holds.

*Proof*. Let $\phi(\alpha)$ be an arbitrary formula. Assume for each ordinal $\beta$, if for each $\gamma\in\beta$, $\phi(\gamma)$ holds, then $\phi(\beta)$ holds. Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary ordinal. Let $\gamma\in\alpha$ be arbitrary. By contradiction, suppose $\phi(\gamma)$ does not hold. Let $\eta$ be the least element of $\alpha$ such that $\phi(\eta)$ does not hold. Therefore for each $\delta\in_{\alpha} \eta$, $\phi(\delta)$ holds. Therefore for each $\delta\in\eta$, $\phi(\delta)$ holds. Therefore $\phi(\eta)$ holds---a contradiction. As a result, $\phi(\gamma)$ holds. Therefore for each $\gamma\in\alpha$, $\phi(\gamma)$ holds. Therefore $\phi(\alpha)$ holds.